# Combine the result of two depending observables (Rxjs)

Tags: angular, rxjs

i have two observables A and B.
I first have to get A until i could take B.

If they are independently i could do something like forkJoin to get the result.
But due to the fact i could take B only after i got A i am struggeling a little.
I tried switchMap, but seems also not to work.

So what i want to achive is:

- get observable A
- get observable B
- combine A and B into a result C

  ```
  public loadConfiguration(): Observable<ProductConfiguration> {
      return this.service.getA().pipe(
       switchMap(response => {
        return this.service.getB(response.id);
       }
      ),
     map(result => this.getData(result)) // here i want A and B thogether so result should contain A and B
    );
  }
  ```

Currently i am a little lost.
Regards
Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
public loadConfiguration(): Observable<ProductConfiguration> {
  return this.service.getA().pipe(
     switchMap(response => {
      return this.service.getB(response.id).pipe(
        map(responseB => ({responseA: response, responseB})),
      );
     }),
     map(result => this.getData(result)) // result already have responseA & responseB
  );
}
```

Or this:

```js
public loadConfiguration(): Observable<ProductConfiguration> {
  return this.service.getA().pipe(
    switchMap(response => {
      return this.service.getB(response.id).pipe(
        map(responseB => this.getData(...)), // you have access to response and responseB here
      );
    }),
  );
}
```

Comment: I choose the first suggestion, cause it was first :-) but thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `zip` method to combine both results of both Observable:

```
public loadConfiguration(): Observable<ProductConfiguration> {
    return this.service.getA().pipe(
        switchMap(response => {
            return Observable.zip(
                this.service.getB(response.id),
                of(response)
            ); 
            return this.service.getB(response.id);
        })),
        .subscribe(([resA, resB]) => {
            console.log('resA', resA);
            console.log('resB', resB);

        }
```

[According to ReactiveX:](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

> `zip` combines the emissions of multiple Observables together via a
>   specified function and emit single items for each combination based on
>   the results of this function

[Work example can be seen at stackbitz.com.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-5az27c?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second argument of the `switchMap` (resultSelector) to combine the result:

```
public loadConfiguration(): Observable<ProductConfiguration> {
        return this.service.getA()
                   .pipe(
                       switchMap(response => this.service.getB(response.id), (a, b) => this.getData({a, b})),
                   );
    }
```

[rxjs learn switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)